# Getting a value of a list element based on keywords

Tags: c#

I have a string with a name returned from database. I need to match it to a different format; that is, I get data in the form of "John Smith", and I need to match it with "Smith,John", which is a one of the options I have to select.

I tried to do it with the use of `All` and `Contains` to check if such option exists, but it seems this fails:

```
bool check = false;
string result = string.Empty;
string myName = "John Smith";
//note the space, this is intentional, as whether there is a space after the comma is inconsistent
var myOptions = new List<string> { "Smith,John", "Doe, Bob" };
var myKeywords = myName.Split(' ').ToList();
if(myKeywords.All(myOptions.Contains))
{
       check = true;
}
```

Given `myName = "John Smith"` I would like to have `result` equal to `Smith,John` (as it's an option on the MyOptions list).

EDIT: thanks for the comments, now i have

```
string result = string.Empty;
string MyName = "John Smith";
//note the space, this is intentional, as whether there is a space after the comma is inconsistent
var MyOptions = new List<string> { "Smith,John", "Doe, Bob" };
var MyKeywords = MyName.Split(' ').ToList();
foreach (var option in MyOptions)
{
    if (MyKeywords.All(option.Contains)) result = option;
}
```

which seems to work. If anyone thinks it could be improved, please point me to it.

EDIT: My next try, this should match "John Smith" to "Smith,John" and "Smith, John", but not to "Alan Smith, John":

```
List<string> temp = MyName.Split(' ').ToList();
string final = string.Empty;
final = string.Join("", temp.Skip(1)) + "," + temp.First();

foreach (var option in MyOptions)
{
    if(option.Replace(" ", string.Empty).Equals(final))
    {
        result = option;
        break;
    }
}
```

Final edit: thanks to @er-mfahhgk , with a little modification, I got my desired result in much more elegant way than the last try:

```
string result = string.Empty;
string myName = "John Smith";

var myOptions = new List<string> { "Smith,John", "van der val, Jeroen" };
var myKeywords = MyName.Split(' ').ToList();
result = MyOptions.Find(x => MyKeywords.All(y => x.Replace(" ", string.Empty).Split(',').Contains(y)));
```

Comment: Try looping through the myKeywords and myOptions to get a better understanding of what's going on: You're trying to find `"Smith,John"` in a list of `John` and `Smith`.

Comment: This is going to get complicated real soon. How do you plan to handle "Edwin van der sar"?

Comment: Since you are splitting full names into single words, I would do the oposite thing. Check if your "single words" are contained in your "option".

Comment: @danish I have no power to change the `myOptions` list or the format of `myName` in the db - I still need to match it. `Edwin van der sar` would be a `van der sar, Edwin` in the `myOptions` list and I would search this list for a value containing `Edwin`, `van`, `der` and `sar`.

Comment: @Yuropoor so the idea is that first word is first name and rest is last name

Comment: @Yuropoor, I added my answer below, try it and let me know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below `if` can `true` when your `John Smith` exactly matches with `Smith,John`.

```
if (MyOptions.Any(x => MyKeywords.All(y => x.Split(',').Contains(y))))
{
    check = true;
}
```

Comment: With a little modification this is exactly what I needed, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try looping through myOptions. Make changes in your code as follows-

```
bool check = false;
            string result = string.Empty;
            string myName = "John Smith";
            //note the space, this is intentional, as whether there is a space after the comma is inconsistent
            var myOptions = new List<string> { "Smith,John", "Doe, Bob" };
            var myKeywords = myName.Split(' ').ToList();

            foreach(string s in myOptions)
            {
                if (myKeywords.All(s.Contains))
                {
                    check = true;
                }
            }
```

However, this is just to give you an idea, you have to test for all the scenarios in this case. This will work even if if the myOptions entry (first name and last name are not exactly equal)

Comment: Yes, consistent with what I have but this will match "John Smith" both with "Smith,John" and "Alan Smith, John"

Answer (score 0):

Something like that ?

```
var myOptions = new List<string> { "Smith,John", "Doe, Bob" };
string myName = "John Smith";
var myKeywords = myName.Split(' ').ToList();

foreach (var myOption in myOptions)
{
     if (Regex.Match(myOption,$"{myKeywords[1]},\\s?{myKeywords[0]}").Success)
     {
            result = myOption;
     }
}
```